# UI Hololens - HandDraggable Issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, hololens

I've recently created a 2D app for the HoloLens. It is a UI Panel with several buttons into it. In order to drag the panel and be positioned as the user wants, I implemented the HanDdraggable.cs functionality (from HoloToolKit). However, whenever I try to move the panel it also rotates.

To change that I modified the Rotation Mode from "Default" to "Orient Towards User" and "Orient Towards User and Keep Uptight". But then It works even worst; if I implement that case, whenever I try to select the panel and drag it to somewhere, the panel runs off from my field of view and it suddenly disappears.

[image: i]

I wanted to ask if somebody has already tried to implement the HandDraggable option into an UI Hololens app and knows how to fix this nodding issue.

Comment: Change the rotation mode? Change the rotation lerp speed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on hololens UI for one of my projects and to manipulate UI I used `TwoHandManipulatable` script which is built into MixedRealityToolKit. In Manipulation Mode of that script you could only set "Move" as an option, and this would allow you to move a menu with two hands, as well as one. (I wanted to have a menu which you can also rotate and scale - which works perfectly with this script, you can lock around which axis you want to have rotation enabled, to avoid unwanted manipulation).

For your script `HandDraggable`, did you try to set `RotationMode` to `Lock Object Rotation`? Sounds like this could solve the problem.